USB network adapter fails after connecting the network cable
I have a usb-network-adapter Realtek rtl8153 and Ubuntu 24.10 / 6.11.0.9.
uname -a            
Linux *** 6.11.0-9-generic #9-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct 14 13:19:59 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -r
Release:    24.10

When I connect the USB adapter without network cable, I can see it in lsusb and in dmesg:
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 011: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter

dmesg
[ 4223.246570] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 4223.259348] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153, bcdDevice=30.00
[ 4223.259363] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[ 4223.259368] usb 4-2: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[ 4223.259371] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 4223.259374] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 000001000000
[ 4223.376689] r8152-cfgselector 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 4223.436354] r8152 4-2:1.0 eth0: v1.12.13
[ 4223.450639] r8152 4-2:1.0 enx00e04c680013: renamed from eth0

But when I connect a network cable, I see:
[ 4913.404575] r8152 4-2:1.0 enx00e04c680013: carrier on
[ 4917.636729] r8152-cfgselector 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 4917.636946] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
[ 4922.085161] usb usb4-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?

and the device disappears from lsusb | grep 8153.
Rarely everything just works, for example after reboot if I reconnect the adapter 3-5 times, it starts sometimes working.
Can you please advice in which direction should I look to find the root cause for this problem?

USB ethernet adapter (Realtek r8153) keeps disconnecting suggests the problem could be a bug in the r8153 driver which doesn't support USB autosuspend, and gives a change to disable USB autosuspend to avoid the issue. The linked answer is from 2018, and are posting as a comment and not an answer as not sure if still applicable to Ubuntu 24.10. Does disabling USB autosuspend help?
